# Plotting a parametric solution from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, parametric-functions, astronomy

Im trying to animate multiple points around multiple parametric plots which depicts orbital motion of body around a planet. Initial conditons are;

```
μ = 3.986004418*10^14
a = {7.92597218162462`*^6, 7.359004757830201`*^6, 
  6.970300551929753`*^6}
r = {7.388961739897817`*^6, 7.352270990873303`*^6, 
  6.989358622500435`*^6}
v = {7589.490674834727`, 7366.424498576473`,7541.464522475139`}
Ecc = {0.014, 0.025, 0.03}(*eccentricity*)
RAAN = {150, 160, 170}
Inc = {20, 80, 320}
ArgPer = {220, 110, 330}
```

The following parametric equations are

```
Table[{x[t] = 
   a[[i]] (1 - Ecc[[i]]^2)/(1 + Ecc[[i]]*Cos[t])*Cos[t],{y[t] = 
   a[[i]] (1 - Ecc[[i]]^2)/(1 + Ecc[[i]]*Cos[t])*Sin[t]}}, {i, 1, 3}]
```

which are used in NDSolve

```
orbsoln = 
 Table[NDSolve[{(x''[
    t] + (μ*(x[t][[i]]))/((x[t][[i]])^2 + (y[t][[i]])^2)^(3/2) == 
  0, (y''[
    t] + (μ* (y[t][[i]]))/((x[t][[i]])^2 + (y[t][[i]])^2)^(3/2) ==
   0, x[0] == r[[j]], y[0] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][x][0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == v[[j]]}, {x , 
y}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], {j, 1, 3}]
```

The results are then plotted using Animate and rotated into plane using an euler rotation matrix

```
EulerRotationMatrix[{i_, Ω_, ω_}] := RotationMatrix[
i, {0, 0, 1}].RotationMatrix[Ω, {0, 1, 
 0}].RotationMatrix[ω, {0, 0, 1}];

 plot = Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[(EulerRotationMatrix[{RAAN[[m]] Degree, Inc[[m]] Degree, 
     ArgPer[[m]] Degree}].{x[t], y[t], 0}) /. First[orbsoln]], {t,
 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 0.8*10^7], {m, 1, 3}]

Animate[Show[plot, 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Red, 
    Point[Table[
  Evaluate[(EulerRotationMatrix[{RAAN[[o]] Degree, 
        Inc[[o]] Degree, ArgPer[[o]] Degree}].{x[t], y[t], 0}) /. 
    First[orbsoln]], {o, 1, 3}]]}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I'm aiming to show 3 points following their parametric path that has been defined by `NDsolve`, but all i get is this plot;

[image]

and the error message

> Coordinate {{{6.978455209925671*^6, 1.4717698904511775*^6, 1.9318209890130716*^6}}, {{-1.9573444509619826]*^6, -6.669739440694639*^6, 2.5060436058655437*^6}}, {{-4.195765089771511*^6, 4.47488342280073*^6, 4.119204986980711*^6}}} should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form.

Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: orbsoln doesn't work properly

Answer (score 2):

Your expression for assigning values to `x[t]` and `y[t]` look suspect.

```
Table[
  {x[t] = a[[i]] (1 - Ecc[[i]]^2)/(1 + Ecc[[i]]*Cos[t])*Cos[t],
    {y[t] = a[[i]] (1 - Ecc[[i]]^2)/(1 + Ecc[[i]]*Cos[t])*Sin[t]}}, 
  {i, 1, 3}]
```

generates

[image: table]

but most of that is thrown away;`x[t]`, `y[t]` are just

```
Column[{x[t], y[t]}]
```

[image: column]

I find it hard to believe this what you want.

#### Update

After I spent quite a bit more time studying your code I concluded that main error is in formulating `orbsoln`. However, I going to ignore it, because I think it might not be necessary for what you want to do.

```
μ = 3.986004418*10^14;
a = {7.92597218162462`*^6, 7.359004757830201`*^6, 6.970300551929753`*^6};
r = {7.388961739897817`*^6, 7.352270990873303`*^6, 6.989358622500435`*^6};
v = {7589.490674834727`, 7366.424498576473`, 7541.464522475139`};
Ecc = {0.014, 0.025, 0.03};
RAAN = {150, 160, 170};
Inc = {20, 80, 320};
ArgPer = {220, 110, 330};

EulerRotationMatrix[{i_, Ω_, ω_}] := 
  RotationMatrix[i, {0, 0, 1}] . 
    RotationMatrix[Ω, {0, 1, 0}] . 
      RotationMatrix[ω, {0, 0, 1}]
```

All you really need is the table of orbit expressions written this way.

```
Block[{t, orbits2D},
  orbits2D =
    Transpose[
      {Table[
         a[[i]] (1 - Ecc[[i]]^2)/(1 + Ecc[[i]]*Cos[t])*Cos[t], {i, 1, 3}],
       Table[
         a[[i]] (1 - Ecc[[i]]^2)/(1 + Ecc[[i]]*Cos[t])*Sin[t], {i, 1, 3}], 
       {0, 0, 0}}];
  orbits3D =
    {orb[1][t_], orb[2][t_], orb[3][t_]} = 
      Table[
        EulerRotationMatrix[
          {RAAN[[m]] Degree, Inc[[m]] Degree, ArgPer[[m]] Degree}].orbits2D[[m]], 
        {m, 1, 3}]];
```

Now we can make the background plot showing the orbit traces with

```
plot = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ orbits3D, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
```

and make a demonstration showing particles following those obits with `Manipulate`. I leave it to you to convert the `Manipulate` to an `Animate expression if that's what you prefer. It's an easy exercise.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
   plot,
   Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[Evaluate[orb[#][t] & /@ Range[3]]]}]],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: demo]

Note: As the problem is reformulated here, the independent variable `t` does not represent time. So this is a purely kinematic solution. The orbital parameters `μ`, `r` and `v` are not used. I think you were trying to get the true dynamics of the orbits with `orbsoln`, but I find that code so confusing that I don't see how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
 im trying to use the individual column values of x[t] and y[t] in NDsolve, i thought this was working as parametric plots were generated for the respective parametric paths.

Could you explain why although the paths are generated, the animated points are not?

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be useful as a reference to demonstrate a side-by-side comparison of two ways to visualize [Keplerian orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit) from their [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements), either by using the exact polar equations, or by using `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`:

```
μ = QuantityMagnitude[PlanetData["Earth", "GravitationalConstantMassProduct"]];

(* semimajor axes *)
A = {7.92597218162462`*^6, 7.359004757830201`*^6, 6.970300551929753`*^6};
(* eccentricities *)
ε = {0.014, 0.025, 0.03};

(* argument of periapsis *)
ω = {220, 110, 330} °;
(* inclination *)
ι = {20, 80, 320} °;
(* longitude of the ascending node *)
Ω = {150, 160, 170} °;

kepler[a_, e_, θ_] := a (1 - e^2)/(1 + e Cos[θ])

orbit = ParametricNDSolveValue[{r''[t] == -μ r[t]/Norm[r[t]]^3, 
                                r[0] == {a (1 - e), 0}, 
                                r'[0] == {0, Sqrt[μ (1 + e)/(a (1 - e))]}}, 
                               r, {t, 0, 2 π a Sqrt[a/μ]}, {a, e}];

GraphicsRow[{ParametricPlot3D[MapThread[
                       Function[{a, e, Ω, ι, ω},
                                Append[kepler[a, e, θ] AngleVector[θ], 0] .
                                EulerMatrix[{Ω, ι, ω}, {3, 1, 3}]],
                       {A, ε, Ω, ι, ω}] // Evaluate, {θ, 0, 2 π},
                       PlotLabel -> "Exact"],
             ParametricPlot3D[MapThread[Function[{a, e, Ω, ι, ω},
                              Append[IdentityMatrix[2], {0, 0}] .
                              orbit[a, e][a Sqrt[a/μ] t] .
                              EulerMatrix[{Ω, ι, ω}, {3, 1, 3}]],
                              {A, ε, Ω, ι, ω}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2 π},
                              PlotLabel -> "NDSolve"]},
            PlotLabel -> "Keplerian Orbits"]
```

[image: Kepler orbits]